# Fyne. Как изменить контент?

Tags: golang

Есть одно окно, в котором при загрузке отображается картинка а, при нажатии на кнопку должна поменяться на картинку b. Но не меняется.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/canvas"
    "fyne.io/fyne/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

func main() {

    application := app.New()
    window := application.NewWindow("win")

    image := canvas.NewImageFromFile("a.png")
    image.FillMode = canvas.ImageFillOriginal
    go canvas.Refresh(image)

    button := widget.NewButton("button", func() {
        fmt.Println("xxx")
        image = canvas.NewImageFromFile("b.png")
        image.FillMode = canvas.ImageFillOriginal
    })
    content := fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewVBoxLayout(), image, button)
    window.SetContent(content)

    window.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не нужно менять текущий контейнер. Нет методов для ее изменения, вы можете только создать контейнеры, управлять их видимостью, после перерисовать экран.

я немного переделал ваше приложение, чтобы оно делало то, что вы хотите.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "fyne.io/fyne"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/canvas"
    "fyne.io/fyne/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

func main() {
    application := app.New()
    window := application.NewWindow("win")

    imageA := canvas.NewImageFromFile("a.png")
    imageA.FillMode = canvas.ImageFillOriginal

    imageB := canvas.NewImageFromFile("b.png")
    imageB.FillMode = canvas.ImageFillOriginal

    var contentA *fyne.Container
    var contentB *fyne.Container
    buttonA := widget.NewButton("change to B", func() {
        fmt.Println("xxx")
        window.SetContent(contentB)
        window.Show()
    })
    buttonB := widget.NewButton("change to A", func() {
        fmt.Println("yyy")
        window.SetContent(contentA)
        window.Show()

    })
    contentA = fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewVBoxLayout(), imageA, buttonA)
    contentB = fyne.NewContainerWithLayout(layout.NewVBoxLayout(), imageB, buttonB)

    window.SetContent(contentA)
    window.ShowAndRun()
}
```